# Using 'On the night'

Tags: expressions

When I was on my English academy I was told that to refer to something that happens at night I should use 'at' and not 'on'. However, there is a Dire Strait album called '[On the night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Night)' so that title always shocked me as I saw that title as incoherent with that rule. Please, could you somebody clarify me if it the title is correct and if so why?

Comment: Hello Ernesto. Lyrics writers and poets don't have to follow grammatical rules. Also, you need to note that the definite article *the* is used in the prepositional phrase. What does your research show?

Comment: Hi Rathony. Normally I don't worry about grammar when listening a song or poem but I always was curious about that choice for an album title. I am happy with Max answer for this but thanks for your comment.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for let me know, I was not aware of the rules when I wrote the post. Did research a bit about the topic in the past though, but never reached a clear conclusion. For what I found, I t was clear to me that 'on the night of the ...' was correct but I never saw the use of 'On the night' by itself. I think Max Williams answered my question so I guess we can close this topic. However, I will include a more extensive research in further questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"at night" simply refers to something that happens **generally** during the night-time, so we'd say "Bats come out at night" for example.

The phrase *"On the night"* has a different meaning:  it's referring to **a specific night** (or an **evening**), and is commonly used to refer to a **performance**.   So, we have the phrase *"It'll be alright on the night"* for example, meaning "It will be alright when we do the actual performance".

It's also used as part of a larger phrase when we're talking about something that happened on a particular night - so the police might ask someone "Where were you on the night of the 12th of July?".

It's my guess that it's the first usage that's being referred to in the album title, ie it's referring to a performance.  I just googled it and it's a live album, so that makes sense: it's how the band played **on the night** of the recording.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your explanation, much clear now.